# Graphics Device initialization failed for : es2, sw

Tags: 14.04, java, gtk3

I am getting following error while running [Kangaroo Test Automation](http://www.kangarootest.com/)

```
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:280)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:220)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:173)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:206)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:649)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:312)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:303)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:94)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:206)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:649)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:312)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:303)
    ... 5 more
```

i google it and fount i mailed application developer and he replied i have to install gtk3 so i tried following packages

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev
sudo apt-get install libswt-gtk-3-java
```

even-thought it's not working can anybody help me why..?

my java -version is

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_40-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-internal-b27)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)
```

i went through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185156/javafx-on-linux-is-showing-a-graphics-device-initialization-failed-for-es2-s
even-though not able to figure out solution.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old question but I just ran into the same problem with ubuntu 14.04 and trying run thinkorswim. My problem was caused because i was using the 32 bit version of the jre. when I installed the 64 bit version of java the errors disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I had exact the same problem under openSUSE13.2 with eclipse. Solution was to move the jfxrt.jar file (can be found in Java SE Development Kit 8u45 tarball) to:

```
/usr/lib64/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar
```

Not to /usr/lib64/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar as I did before.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. It took me several days to figure this out. The error clearly mentions that the problem is with javafx.graphics. You may have downloaded your JavaFX package from JavaFX probably Gluon. You have downloaded the LTS version. All files in this version work but the javafx.graphics. LTS is a good version therefore do not uninstall it. Instead, download an early access version from JavaFX - Gluon. Unzip it and replace the lib of your previously downloaded JavaFX with the lib of the new download. This solves the issue 100%.

Comment: Do you mean that we should only use a particular file from the early access version? If so, which file... Can you explain the process more?

Comment: Download the whole Early Access Version. Then replace only the lib folder of LTS version with the lib folder of Early Access Version.

Comment: And also remember to do the configuration accurately. Things to consider are adding JavaFX library, adding .jar files from the lib folder into Modulepath (properties-java build path-modulepath) and adding VM arguments in run configuration arguments section.